# Git is failing to Stage, or commit with SourceTree in a Windows network environment

Tags: windows, git, networking, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Atlassian SourceTree to look after some git repositories, however when I create a new one and try to add new files for the first time (not sure if it's essential info for getting help), but this is the error message I get when I try to commit a file:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false add -f -- app/file.txt
error: unable to create temporary file: File exists
error: app/file.txt: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file app/file.txt

fatal: adding files failed

Completed with errors, see above.
```

It's a little annoying, because it's not storing anything.

I'm doing this at work under a Novell/Windows environment, so it could be a permission error, but I figured if I'm browsing the network and logged in as me, surely the SourceTree internal git program would store and look at the network as to who it's logged in as.

It works great if I'm using a source directory locally, but it doesn't work on a shared path.

We've even tried it with a direct CIFS path, and a \servername\path.

Comment: Looks like it can't be done. So instead I'm working on a local git repository, and copying the entire path. Not the best method. But it'll at least let others still see the files (who don't have git access)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround (since it might be related to a [external user directories issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/External+user+directories)), you could:

- initialize and add your files locally
- clone that local repo to the target external shared path.